# Angular2: generating checkboxes issue

Tags: javascript, angular

I've got the following template:

```
<div *ngFor="#weekday of weekdays" class="checkbox">
    <label>
        <input
            #{{weekday}}
            (change)="selectWeekday('{{weekday}}', {{weekday}}.checked)"
            type="checkbox"> {{weekday}}
    </label>
</div>
```

Backed by this component:

```
@Component({
    selector: "schedule",
    templateUrl: "app/schedule.html",
})
export class ScheduleComponent {
    public weekdays: string[] = [ "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday" ];

    public selectWeekday(weekday: string, checked: boolean {
        // ...
    }
}
```

I'm getting the following error:

> Got interpolation ({{}}) where expression was expected at column 15 in [selectWeekday('{{weekday}}', {{weekday}}.checked)]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this approach:

```
<div *ngFor="#weekday of weekdays" class="checkbox">
<label>
    <input
        (change)="selectWeekday(weekday, $event.target.checked)"
        type="checkbox"> {{weekday}}
</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Template variables require static names. You can use binding to define such a name.

This is invalid:

```
#{{weekday}}
```

it needs to be something like

```
#weekday
```

(won't bind to your `weekday` property though)
or

```
#monday
```

Comment: So does this mean I can't generate my checkboxes?

Comment: You can add the same `#weekday` template variable to all `<input #weekday`. What's the purpose of this template variable. what do you want to use it for?

Comment: I use the variable to have easy access to the value of the checkbox.

Comment: From outside the `*ngFor`? That won't work this way. You might be able to use `@ViewChildren('weekday') weekdays` and then in `ngAfterViewInit()` assign the values to properties in the component to be used in the view for binding. I admit a bit complicated. Can you edit your question and show more details about how you want to use it? Then I might be able to provider better suggestions.

Comment: Ok, @kemsky spotted in your question how you actually want to use it. That should solve your issue.